# problems on sum arraylist values of same date between two different dates in java

Tags: java, arraylist, nullpointerexception

I written the code for array list  sum the values  if it's same date and store the values in new array list. and i print the list values using JSTL. If i pass the date value between two dates(eg: 2016-08-04,2016-08-05) it's executed Successfully. If i pass the date values of one week it's display empty page. I didn't know where i done the mistake.anyone help me.

This is my listDAO class code

```
package report;

import java.sql.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class ListDAO 
{
    public ListDAO()
    {
      Connection conn=mysqlconnect.ConnecrDb();
    }  
public ArrayList<Product> getlistProduct(String fromdate,String todate)
    {
       ArrayList<Product> listProducts = new ArrayList<Product>();
       Connection conn=null;
       PreparedStatement pst=null;
       ResultSet rst=null;            
       try
       {
                conn=mysqlconnect.ConnecrDb();

                String sql=" select bill_master.bill_no,DATE_FORMAT(bill_master.bill_date, '%Y-%m-%d') AS 'formatted_date',transaction.product_id,transaction.tax_amount,transaction.amount,product_master.Product_name,product_master.vat from bill_master inner join transaction on bill_master.bill_no=transaction.bill_no inner join product_master on transaction.product_id=product_master.product_id where vat='14.50' and DATE_FORMAT(bill_master.bill_date, '%Y-%m-%d')between ? and ?";
                pst= conn.prepareStatement(sql);
                 pst.setString(1, fromdate);
                 pst.setString(2, todate);
                 rst= pst.executeQuery();
                 while(rst.next())
                {
                     listProducts.add(new Product(                      
                       rst.getDate("formatted_date"),                      
                       rst.getDouble("tax_amount"),
                       rst.getDouble("amount"),           
                       rst.getDouble("vat")));
                }


       }
       catch(Exception e)
       {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
        finally {
            if(rst!=null) {
                try {
                    rst.close();
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            if(pst!=null) {
                try {
                    pst.close();
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            if(conn!=null) {
                try {
                    conn.close();
                } 
                catch (SQLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        return listProducts;
    }
```

this is my Product class code

```
package report;
import java.util.Date;

public class Product {

    private  Date formatted_date;    
    private  double tax_amount;
    private  double amount;        
    private  double vat;

    public Product(Date formatted_date, double tax_amount, double amount, double vat) {

        this.formatted_date = formatted_date;        
        this.tax_amount = tax_amount;
        this.amount = amount;        
        this.vat = vat;
    }    

    public Date getFormatted_date() {
        return formatted_date;
    }

    public void setFormatted_date(Date formatted_date) {
        this.formatted_date = formatted_date;
    }


    public double getTax_amount() {
        return tax_amount;
    }

    public void setTax_amount(double tax_amount) {
        this.tax_amount = tax_amount;
    }

    public double getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }

    public void setAmount(double amount) {
        this.amount = amount;
    }   

    public double getVat() {
        return vat;
    }

    public void setVat(double vat) {
        this.vat = vat;
    }  

}
```

This my servlet code

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
           try
           {
             String date1=request.getParameter("startdte");
                    String date2=request.getParameter("enddte");
                    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
                    Date date3 = df.parse(date1);                       
                    SimpleDateFormat format1 = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
                    Date date4 = format1.parse(date2);
                    java.sql.Date sqdate1 = new java.sql.Date(date3.getTime());
                    java.sql.Date sqdate2 = new java.sql.Date(date4.getTime());
                    String date5=sqdate1.toString();
                    String date6=sqdate2.toString();
ListDAO products = new ListDAO();
                    ArrayList<Product> listProducts = products.getlistProduct(date5,date6);
for (int i = 0; i < listProducts.size(); i++) 
                    {
                        Date date7 = listProducts.get(i).getFormatted_date();
                        Double tax = listProducts.get(i).getTax_amount();
                        Double amt = listProducts.get(i).getAmount();
                        Double vat= listProducts.get(i).getVat();
                        Double amt1 = null;
                        Double tax1=null;
                        int k = 0;

                        for (int j = i + 1; j < listProducts.size(); j++) {

                            if (date7.equals(listProducts.get(j).getFormatted_date())) {
                                amt = amt + listProducts.get(j).getAmount();
                                amt1 = new BigDecimal(amt).setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP).doubleValue();
                                tax=tax+listProducts.get(j).getTax_amount();
                                tax1 = new BigDecimal(tax).setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP).doubleValue();
                                k = j;
                            }
                        }
                        listProducts1.add(new Product(date7,tax1, amt1,vat));
                        i += k++;
                    }
                    request.setAttribute("listProducts1", listProducts1);
request.getRequestDispatcher("detailreport.jsp").forward(request, response);
}
```

Tomcat server shows

```
admin
pass
[report.Product@8257aa, report.Product@149677e, report.Product@29b41e, report.Product@1f052ff, report.Product@d8e872, report.Product@8494cd, report.Product@452f68, report.Product@2b8638, report.Product@178f6d4, report.Product@9517a0, report.Product@422b86, report.Product@379080, report.Product@1efe369, report.Product@3b1c1b, report.Product@b27055, report.Product@ece2f6, report.Product@28903c, report.Product@115608e, report.Product@763a60, report.Product@1f2885a, report.Product@1d5db0b, report.Product@11fd81f, report.Product@1a60d09, report.Product@a20429, report.Product@bf470d, report.Product@1d1b746, report.Product@1578cfd, report.Product@e968ff, report.Product@1ec41eb, report.Product@1dbb584, report.Product@16a2ca3, report.Product@1988c50, report.Product@241066, report.Product@1b0b65c, report.Product@945d24, report.Product@6ee8d5, report.Product@1780cb0, report.Product@88fbab, report.Product@142ac57, report.Product@40a11f, report.Product@1121f48, report.Product@c3b5a5, report.Product@ca8e16, report.Product@365e59, report.Product@16c60aa, report.Product@3e47fd, report.Product@e84edd, report.Product@191a947, report.Product@8dbd, report.Product@599d5a, report.Product@1699154, report.Product@1c43709, report.Product@f959cf, report.Product@773a0d, report.Product@18430d9, report.Product@1a303a5, report.Product@1446125]
[report.Product@4fd9b5, report.Product@5e0377, report.Product@35968a, report.Product@2e5098, report.Product@ad48ff, report.Product@937964, report.Product@6aa12, report.Product@187a07a, report.Product@138c925, report.Product@11da5fe, report.Product@17d02c3, report.Product@40885d, report.Product@b8a756, report.Product@f239f1, report.Product@ba1a6c, report.Product@1cbc51, report.Product@8f6bf2, report.Product@1f81bba, report.Product@1e48088, report.Product@b287a5, report.Product@e76512, report.Product@19c9ad9, report.Product@7a58e1, report.Product@615b9f, report.Product@1c646cb, report.Product@51e464, report.Product@69a206, report.Product@10c51c5, report.Product@1cc77b8, report.Product@c7efb3, report.Product@4a0890, report.Product@7843d5, report.Product@1ad7f3f, report.Product@17d2d0a, report.Product@11825bb, report.Product@554195, report.Product@144a179, report.Product@c519d7, report.Product@2399a1, report.Product@13b2983, report.Product@1225816, report.Product@1c536fd, report.Product@9d576c, report.Product@1d68014, report.Product@172a1fd, report.Product@e8fe4d, report.Product@8f8429, report.Product@2dbece, report.Product@14a00f2, report.Product@1841cd6, report.Product@814b4f, report.Product@772fcb, report.Product@e2cd2e, report.Product@c9bfa, report.Product@1d45bf6, report.Product@e19958, report.Product@11a6b1d, report.Product@16e71cc, report.Product@1f14555, report.Product@ff0aea, report.Product@25bc73, report.Product@177348f, report.Product@11bad8d, report.Product@1f2d94, report.Product@e9890e, report.Product@24fdc8, report.Product@91589e, report.Product@5121ad, report.Product@7a0e0c, report.Product@13076b2, report.Product@c0e15a, report.Product@10b0000, report.Product@12d10f2, report.Product@1b3ad9b, report.Product@14aaa58, report.Product@f5b8b1, report.Product@30ad95, report.Product@1d42cfe, report.Product@d5f34d, report.Product@588442, report.Product@1532b15, report.Product@1319134, report.Product@1340b48, report.Product@1d0be3b, report.Product@17922c7, report.Product@1da720b, report.Product@753b62, report.Product@8dbbe3, report.Product@12a40ad, report.Product@fc1e73, report.Product@335020, report.Product@d16b21, report.Product@d0838c, report.Product@16c690e, report.Product@652746, report.Product@f58ff3, report.Product@1bdb9c9, report.Product@f04a60, report.Product@1a2ee56]
[report.Product@12650fe, report.Product@8f8272, report.Product@1bd2346, report.Product@56d7ea, report.Product@1797b37, report.Product@88755b, report.Product@d0d5bf, report.Product@80fb53, report.Product@1f42219, report.Product@eabf4a, report.Product@1b4bfda, report.Product@19fa911, report.Product@114a62e, report.Product@aa2906, report.Product@16b81ac, report.Product@10e7738, report.Product@b53992, report.Product@1d6a4b5, report.Product@d780a3, report.Product@3e4eca, report.Product@a6b921, report.Product@1c44295, report.Product@1ef6a08, report.Product@11a6eae, report.Product@589871, report.Product@802d26, report.Product@1143cec, report.Product@1abc841, report.Product@e83ad3, report.Product@6e2873, report.Product@21ca8e, report.Product@7956a7, report.Product@2827a1, report.Product@41d2b3, report.Product@1700de8, report.Product@1a11cee, report.Product@72878a, report.Product@120795b, report.Product@ff5139, report.Product@2da0c7, report.Product@1968ccf, report.Product@f69a09, report.Product@1fae944, report.Product@1e8a4b1, report.Product@94658c, report.Product@96ceba, report.Product@de398a, report.Product@193bf94, report.Product@10699a3, report.Product@50d026, report.Product@1917935, report.Product@1acaa41, report.Product@ddbb4b, report.Product@13348c1, report.Product@1edaff0, report.Product@1b9bdbb, report.Product@1575fa5, report.Product@14881b8, report.Product@13c58b7, report.Product@e45d2a, report.Product@a0ac5a, report.Product@9367ce, report.Product@18432d0, report.Product@241122, report.Product@1e10dd3, report.Product@52c3b1, report.Product@1adaf2c, report.Product@1c781f3, report.Product@1249b48, report.Product@4ec4c4, report.Product@1584f34, report.Product@b7fb4f, report.Product@d402fb, report.Product@10fb979, report.Product@159ba8e, report.Product@1e6cda2, report.Product@1c670b0, report.Product@11036cc, report.Product@17dc71e, report.Product@9bc1e8, report.Product@1d7a748, report.Product@1277a5a, report.Product@d1bcbd, report.Product@1be5835, report.Product@1913bf7, report.Product@1f7e75f, report.Product@771836, report.Product@d6bf03, report.Product@968872, report.Product@d7fce0, report.Product@1adbaf, report.Product@14cf495, report.Product@14d66f8, report.Product@a331c8, report.Product@197e51, report.Product@1b422f9, report.Product@1643564, report.Product@1ed4b69, report.Product@1f20691, report.Product@8d4191, report.Product@1cbbdda, report.Product@11d5b1c, report.Product@48ca69, report.Product@e0d685, report.Product@123b94a, report.Product@59b317, report.Product@fcb25d, report.Product@22099c, report.Product@a5206f, report.Product@f46720, report.Product@19e9cbb, report.Product@43e3e0, report.Product@125b151, report.Product@19c71be, report.Product@1ef9fee, report.Product@ed01d3, report.Product@12dcbd, report.Product@5a08a3, report.Product@ed4623, report.Product@197c93c, report.Product@1cabfd, report.Product@5f91fa, report.Product@68cff9, report.Product@12e036b, report.Product@1e26875, report.Product@137e178, report.Product@1b3bb0a, report.Product@bcc0a9, report.Product@cae31, report.Product@80215a, report.Product@d9e04, report.Product@1562f, report.Product@1c14b91, report.Product@1481d7d, report.Product@18816ec, report.Product@198f74e, report.Product@1944387, report.Product@dd654a, report.Product@124e3df, report.Product@ec5365, report.Product@1571597, report.Product@4a9a53, report.Product@1d9f295, report.Product@1c54456, report.Product@97230, report.Product@27de92, report.Product@185497a, report.Product@19aef85, report.Product@e31a19, report.Product@1c69e56, report.Product@c54b12, report.Product@c39565, report.Product@852cbe, report.Product@13c80ad, report.Product@123efed]
[report.Product@106b52e, report.Product@1610891, report.Product@1796f7a, report.Product@185c8e2, report.Product@4786d4, report.Product@1e4ec58, report.Product@588660, report.Product@1de37fd, report.Product@2ddfb2, report.Product@1b94f6c, report.Product@10d4698, report.Product@95c26b, report.Product@f0a62, report.Product@172c9cf, report.Product@11f6b1e, report.Product@1b1b790, report.Product@8a8c54, report.Product@2f9be, report.Product@15a6472, report.Product@178b17b, report.Product@cc0e46, report.Product@bd5192, report.Product@136489f, report.Product@d9c57f, report.Product@1354999, report.Product@1730eb1, report.Product@c9a702, report.Product@f3820b, report.Product@deb73b, report.Product@1cf966c, report.Product@19cc1b2, report.Product@70c556, report.Product@1abb955, report.Product@114a349, report.Product@1ec310d, report.Product@1887472, report.Product@1951022, report.Product@15645b6, report.Product@fae5c1, report.Product@1f1ca, report.Product@1a93b25, report.Product@16a0d74, report.Product@1993f80, report.Product@17f586, report.Product@f863c0, report.Product@15d03fc, report.Product@1b0c025, report.Product@116fea1, report.Product@a71327, report.Product@da869a, report.Product@baf535, report.Product@388498, report.Product@891f79, report.Product@7179a0, report.Product@1e82eff, report.Product@656e7b, report.Product@1385084, report.Product@2e4221, report.Product@f78ac6, report.Product@1b7e647, report.Product@6f6627, report.Product@19b95f2, report.Product@1917a0f, report.Product@1e4893c, report.Product@edcc58, report.Product@2a5e1, report.Product@1d89662, report.Product@790515, report.Product@13cb761, report.Product@12b5d9b, report.Product@ea62f, report.Product@1c06a27, report.Product@179461d, report.Product@ea2c1c, report.Product@1f61b27, report.Product@70c674, report.Product@1f4fd63, report.Product@1278a41, report.Product@e5e64f, report.Product@1737814, report.Product@1d08a9e, report.Product@3c8d06, report.Product@14ebe7b, report.Product@bb8931, report.Product@2c09fc, report.Product@1439b2d, report.Product@180aa0e, report.Product@1c8a36, report.Product@1b6074a, report.Product@198a5cb, report.Product@acedb7, report.Product@12a9f44, report.Product@13e49c2, report.Product@5c6345, report.Product@1794c53, report.Product@81f998, report.Product@129aa04, report.Product@5909ed, report.Product@19ad6ff]
[report.Product@eb342, report.Product@11ab736, report.Product@f260bf, report.Product@adbffc, report.Product@11763cc, report.Product@98ecca, report.Product@1e200a7, report.Product@98fbe3, report.Product@1c10d02, report.Product@13d0455, report.Product@e780ad, report.Product@b10653, report.Product@165453, report.Product@1fa28ae, report.Product@84b98c, report.Product@1b1a4f4, report.Product@1c4b705, report.Product@1cbcf19, report.Product@1897b6f, report.Product@106e35c, report.Product@138bced, report.Product@1fbabd5, report.Product@1ce3940, report.Product@109ece, report.Product@129ee9f, report.Product@1f122f7, report.Product@2e892d, report.Product@12ff6c8, report.Product@1f2f85e, report.Product@8ffbe9, report.Product@e3bbd5, report.Product@140b813, report.Product@1f51218, report.Product@77056f, report.Product@5cd1d, report.Product@dd2bf4, report.Product@70c691, report.Product@1fc9a71, report.Product@ff8018, report.Product@32c1d0, report.Product@525141, report.Product@548291, report.Product@480c1e, report.Product@13bf29, report.Product@6b21ea, report.Product@17f9525, report.Product@118daf6, report.Product@cf7c3a, report.Product@1e4c961, report.Product@1611dff, report.Product@f86592, report.Product@1d4683a, report.Product@6f860, report.Product@19c68b0, report.Product@19d2eed, report.Product@740b0f, report.Product@821a88, report.Product@19c0524, report.Product@15888a, report.Product@1b75168, report.Product@41b2e9, report.Product@148f6b8, report.Product@13dd8da, report.Product@167da14, report.Product@11e7898, report.Product@17f47d5, report.Product@145094f, report.Product@166492a, report.Product@4d9d89, report.Product@1a19ffd, report.Product@ece25, report.Product@1ffe345, report.Product@a1c910, report.Product@1974405, report.Product@1f2a92e, report.Product@412085, report.Product@1be3a77, report.Product@1f08073, report.Product@813354, report.Product@510044, report.Product@1e8ac04, report.Product@757508, report.Product@15692b8, report.Product@ba74df, report.Product@14ef470, report.Product@920fca, report.Product@14aca5b, report.Product@12b35a5, report.Product@1cef6b3, report.Product@a67e64, report.Product@b41310, report.Product@4fb003, report.Product@1ac951d, report.Product@171dc32, report.Product@2f6ce6, report.Product@19690f5, report.Product@6fafb, report.Product@47831d, report.Product@f0ec3d, report.Product@125d6d3, report.Product@13abf70, report.Product@1ee78a5, report.Product@132d93a, report.Product@1538918, report.Product@14daf57, report.Product@132b4eb, report.Product@3d0b7, report.Product@7babb8, report.Product@146f6b9, report.Product@1f0103e, report.Product@1ba5877, report.Product@105ef91, report.Product@b31f45, report.Product@1c9eb5e, report.Product@17ba1a8, report.Product@1b235f9, report.Product@f584d8, report.Product@e4a239, report.Product@566856, report.Product@dc1576, report.Product@1050cfc, report.Product@978760, report.Product@38e859, report.Product@1e3a8f, report.Product@9697e3, report.Product@cdcbdf, report.Product@103d33a, report.Product@2094be, report.Product@10560ae, report.Product@e63ef, report.Product@c2f995, report.Product@8fcd98, report.Product@102e8b5, report.Product@1fbeb99, report.Product@28aeba, report.Product@e76ccf, report.Product@198bcc3, report.Product@90caed, report.Product@1facd7f, report.Product@c94fea, report.Product@9d964f, report.Product@1f7336b, report.Product@50c52b, report.Product@c0b33e, report.Product@137e025, report.Product@15cd942, report.Product@bb903e, report.Product@1faf7a5, report.Product@1989fc9, report.Product@1227c4e, report.Product@10f1ee9, report.Product@1b65ab8, report.Product@fdfb6d, report.Product@85b2a3, report.Product@193250b]
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at report.ReportServlet.doGet(ReportServlet.java:104)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:436)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1078)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
[report.Product@154e343, report.Product@14456a, report.Product@d94ff0, report.Product@10f1a19, report.Product@7a9a52, report.Product@129b107, report.Product@2559bb, report.Product@260a37, report.Product@168d64c, report.Product@1cd249c, report.Product@11e974f, report.Product@15fcd57, report.Product@a22a3b, report.Product@82b700, report.Product@1bc6e98, report.Product@fc9f, report.Product@c932ee, report.Product@12ec047, report.Product@51ab43, report.Product@1c2fb78, report.Product@baf44, report.Product@11fd4e1, report.Product@d115e5, report.Product@f48980, report.Product@6f6020, report.Product@fe47c, report.Product@1619a5c, report.Product@dd2f8c, report.Product@15cc930, report.Product@9cad96, report.Product@485744, report.Product@15965d2, report.Product@2bc9f7, report.Product@d8afa2, report.Product@1f2f4b6, report.Product@1a01539, report.Product@d1626e, report.Product@952e6f, report.Product@1b9982, report.Product@1fb4087, report.Product@49a0b5, report.Product@1d5f026, report.Product@897cdd, report.Product@64c8d6, report.Product@bd7580, report.Product@6d301c, report.Product@71a991, report.Product@3395cc, report.Product@afa1ee, report.Product@b018d0, report.Product@12d3e9d, report.Product@169d5d2, report.Product@154e85c, report.Product@163260a, report.Product@567e1c, report.Product@7199e2, report.Product@2de475]
```

Comment: You basically asked "Why do I get a NullPointerException?". The duplicate answers that. Once you're capable to ask "Why is variable X null?" while pointing out the exact variable X in a [mcve], and you still can't figure out the root cause, then feel free to ask a new question.

Comment: i using NullPointerExceptionProgram obj=new NullPointerExceptionProgram();
                if(obj!=null)
                { }  again its shows the error